# Is it possible to convert an Angular Project to an IOS-App without having a Mac?

Tags: angular, iphone

I built an Angular application, which I wanted to convert to an IOS-App.
I found the Capacitor plugin but to convert it completely I need a Mac PC/Xcode.

Is there anything else i can use?

I did everything with Capacitor but when i execute

```
npx cap open ios
```

it just opens a folder, in my understanding it should open Xcode, which a cant download

I also brought the folders on my Iphone but i dont understand how i should execute the app

Comment: just embebed in [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) -copy your dist folder in the www folder-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it without a Mac, I prefer you install a virtual machine on your device using `vmware` you can check this article from [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/macos-windows-10-virtual-machine/)

Answer (score -1):

Check out Capacitor. Capacitor is a cross-platform native runtime to build modern web apps that can run natively on iOS or Android with ease. It offers cool features like PWA support, Capacitor CLI, and awesome plugins.

Comment: I did but i need to configure it with XCode with i cant install cause i got an Windows PC

Comment: You can create Virtual Machine for MacOS.

Comment: You still need a Mac for that. Downvoting...

Answer (score -1):

If you can then convert your project to Angular with NativeScript. Its a cross platform framework which allows to develop android, iOS and web apps.

Below are some links-

NativeScript and Angular Docs
https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/angular.html

Udemy Course
https://www.udemy.com/course/nativescript-angular-build-native-ios-android-web-apps/

Comment: You still need a Mac for that. Downvoting...